# Strange issue with fixed form border styles in Vista

Tags: c#, .net, forms, coding-style, border

My previous post about this issue didn't got too many answers and it was kinda specific and hard to understand. I think I've managed to understand the problem better and I now believe it to be a Vista issue...

The problem lies on all types of fixed border styles like FixedDialog, Fixed3D, FixedSingle and FixedToolWindow. It does not happen on the sizable ones. This problem, like I said, it also happens only on Vista.

Let's say you have a form with any of the fixed border styles and set the starting location to 0,0. What you want here is for the form to be snapped to the top left corner of the screen. This works just fine if the form border style is one of the sizable options, if it's fixed, well, the form will be a little bit outside of the screen working area both to the left and top.

What's more strange about this is that the form location does not change, it sill is 0,0, but a few pixels of the form are still drawn outside of the working screen area.

I tested this on XP and it didn't happen, the problem is Vista specific. On XP, the only difference was the border size that change a bit between any of the styles. But the form was always perfectly snapped to position 0,0.

If possible, **without** finding how many pixels are being drawn outside of the working area and then add that to the form location, is there a possible way to fix or workaround this?

Comment: This is essentially the same question you asked earlier, but with added details. Really should have been edited into previous...

Comment: I don't think so, it's actually a bit different. Your solution on the other question might solve that question but it doesn't solve the problem on this one. Which is more related to my real issue. I actually don't want the form to be dragged outside of the working area (your solution in the other question doesn't prevent that). I also don't want the size to of the form to change when I switch borders but that's secondary and I consider it an "additional problem" that I'll have to deal with later after this one is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Aero is enabled, Windows will lie to you about the size and position of `Fixed*` `FormBorderStyle` windows.  The following code shows how to get the correct height and top-offset of such a Window.  A similar technique will allow you to place a window at (0,0).

```
[DllImport("dwmapi.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
public static extern bool DwmIsCompositionEnabled();

// When Aero is enabled, and our FormBorderStyle is FixedToolWindow,
//    Windows will lie to us about our size and position.
public bool AeroIsMessingWithUs()
{
    bool ret = false;
    try
    {
        // check for other Fixed styles here if needed
        if (FormBorderStyle == System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow)
        {
            if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6 && DwmIsCompositionEnabled())
            {
                // Aero is enabled
                ret = true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    return ret;
}

public int MyWindowHeight()
{
    int height = Height;
    if (AeroIsMessingWithUs())
    {
        // there are actually 5 more pixels on the top and bottom
        height += 10;
    }
    return height;
}

public int MyWindowY()
{
    int y = Location.Y;
    if (AeroIsMessingWithUs())
    {
        // I'm actually 5 pixels higher than Windows says I am
        y -= 5;
    }
    return y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason I want to do this is to allow my application, which has a skin applied, to enable or disable that skin. The whole application is working fine with the skin and I was trying to implement a property to enable and disable the skin. The issue on this topic was one of the problems I'm having when the skin is disabled. I then realized that I also have a lot of other annoying problems to deal with if the skin is disabled. Which means I'll just forget about this feature for now and leave the skin always on in the time being. I just don't have the time to handle so many issues right now...

Proposing to close this question...